# I want to find a closed form of the sum $\sum_{i=1}^n x^{i^2}$

Tags: calculus, abstract-algebra, algebra-precalculus

Is there any closed form of the following sum?

$\sum_{i=1}^n x^{i^2}$, where $x$ is a variable.

Calculating the sum for a first few $n$ does not give any pattern.

Comment: Are there any restrictions on $x$? (Such as $|x| < 1$)

Comment: @mardat I don't have any restriction on $x$. But if you have a closed form with a restriction on $x$, please tell me it.

Comment: No, there is no closed form for that sum. Proof: if there were one, I would have come across it by now.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: the OP actually wants a finite sum. I have no idea what could be done with that in the way of simplification.

ORIGINAL:

This is standard, see the definition in formula (1.3) and the relationship to the Dedekind eta function. See also [THETA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theta_function)

==============

[image]

================

Comment: Is there any similar formula for a finite sum?

Comment: @Snow, I did not notice your sum was finite. I will leave this answer here, it is information of a sort. I do not see any simplification for your finite sum.